# Fill in a web form with Get values in the URL; issues with field names

Tags: html, forms, get

I am trying to fill in an HTML form, using Get requests and am having some inconsistent results.

The form is https://wwwapps.ups.com/ctc .
Filling in the first field is easy.  By inspection of the page source, I found the name of the first field is "orgCity".  Accordingly, I constructed a URL https://www.apps.ups.com?orgCity=Guyton .  This works great in that when I enter that URL in my browser, the form with the first field filled in with "Guyton" is rendered.

Hower, I run into problems when I try to add the second field.  The name of the second  field is origPostalCode.  Using https://wwwapps.ups.com/ctc?origCity=Guyton&origPostalCode=31312 does not work as desired.  An error message appears on the form.

By experimenting, I found that by making the second form field name origPostal in the URL, https://wwwapps.ups.com/ctc?origCity=Guyton&origPostal=31312 the form is rendered as originally desired.  However, I am using an incorrect, apparently arbitrary field ID.  I suspect that some code (javascript) is responsible for generating the error message when the field name that appears when the source code is viewed (in the browser) is used.  I have no idea why a different field name seems to work, or how that filed name can be determined (other than experimentally).

Having to use a form field name that is not what is specified in the form code to get the form to fill correctly is a nightmare, in that experimentation could be endless, and in fact, may not result in something that works, or that is stable.

I am using FirefFox Quantum 64.0.2, and get the same results with Chrome.
Can anyone tell me what is going on, and how I successfully identify and use the correct form field names.

Comment: Maybe because this is the UPS website, and it is not intended for people to randomly guess names to fill in the form. Try searching for UPS documentation for API or some official documentation that explains how to properly use it.

Comment: 9 of the 11 fields I have used so far work fine, using the field name that is shown when the page source is viewed.  Only 2 do not work that way.  Although I suspect UPS is doing something different with these 2 fields, it should not be that hard to find out what EXACTLY they are doing, and not suppose the issue is due to UPS intent. Using the API is another way to get the information, but much more complex.  In addition, using the Get variables has much broader usefulness.

Comment: *but much more complex* - it may have a steeper learning curve, but using an API is far preferable to attempting to keep up with changing web pages

Comment: If you're concerned about gumming up the works somewhere down the line, use the api : https://www.ups.com/us/en/help-center/technology-support/developer-resource-center.page You might do a little reading, But you'll learn how to interact with their services (web services).

Comment: Yes, the API route is probably a better way to get the UPS information, but I want to know how to fill in all the fields of the UPS web form from my HTML page.  In this case, it is not the data that I desire as much as the knowledge of how to fill in the form from another webpage.It should be easy, and for most of the form elements it is.  I just want to understand how to deal with the non trivial form elements of the UPS form.